# Pixel wise classification using Convolutional Neural Network?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution

The question is conceptual. I basically understand how MNIST example works, the feedforward net takes an image as input and output a predicted label 0 to 9.

I'm working on a project that ideally will take an image as the input, and for every pixel on that image, I will output a probability of that pixel being a certain label or not.

So my input, for example is of the size 600 * 800 * 3 pixels, and my output would be 600 * 800, where every single entry on my output is a probability.

How can I design the pipeline for that using Convolutional Neural Network? I'm working with Tensorflow. Thanks

---

Elaboration:

Basically I wanted to label every pixel as either foreground or background (The probability of the pixel being foreground). My intuition is that in convolutional layers, the neurons will be able to pick up information in a patch around that pixel, and finally be able to tell how likely this pixel could be the foreground.

Comment: How can a single pixel be classified as a certain label? Can you elaborate a little more? Maybe a group of pixels ,but a single pixel classified as a label its difficult to visualize

Comment: This is basically semantic segmentation, look at the paper "Fully Convolutional Networks for Semantic Segmentation" for more information.

Comment: @LuisLeal I wanted to label every pixel as either foreground or background (The probability of the pixel being foreground). My intuition is that in convolutional layers, the neurons will be able to pick up information in a patch around that pixel, and finally be able to tell how likely this pixel could be the foreground.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Thanks, I will check out that paper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it wouldn't be very efficient, a naive method could be to color a window (say, 5px x 5px) of pixels black, record the probabilities for each output class, then slide the window over a bit, then record again. This would be repeated until the window passed over the whole image.

Now we have some interesting information. For each window position, we know the delta of the probability distribution over the labels compared to the probabilities when the classifier received the whole image. That delta corresponds to the amount that that region contributed to the classifier making that decision.

If you want this mapped down to a per-pixel level for visualization purposes, you could use a stride length of 1 pixel when sliding the window and map the probability delta to the centermost pixel of the window.

Note that you don't want to make the window too small, otherwise the deltas will be too small to make a difference. Also, you'll probably want to be a bit smart about how you choose the color of the window so the window itself doesn't appear to be a feature to the classifier.

Edit in response to your elaboration:
This would still work for what you're trying to do. In fact, it becomes a bit nicer even. Instead of keeping all the label probability deltas separate, you would sum them. This would give you measurement which tells you "how much does this region make the image more like a number" (or in other words, the foreground). Also, you wouldn't measure the deltas against the uncovered image, but rather against the vector of probabilities where P(x)=0 for each label.